# OpenGL ES 2.0 slow FPS

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

So I am making a simple 3D stereoscopic (2 viewports) maze game, the world is 10 x 10 Cubes wide.  I am running this in Android JAVA not NDK. On a Nexus 5, I get around 55-58fps and then it drops to around 40.  Seeing things like Minecraft must have thousands of cubes, I expected a permanent 60fps.

At a maximum I am rendering 80 Cubes (+ 1 sphere, 2 billboards) (10 x 10 - the actual pathway), they are textured and I have per pixel lighting on my fragment shader (its a horror game)

Any advice? could it be the textures?

```
private void drawScene(float[] VMatrix, float[] PMatrix) {

        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);

        // Static map walls (repeated textures
        leftWall.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);
        rightWall.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);
        backWall.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);
        frontWall.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);

        // Render Maze made out of Cubes (Maze is up to 10 x 10 cubes) textured
        if (cubeList != null) {
            for (Cube placeMarker : cubeList) {
                if (placeMarker.loadedTexture == false) {
                    placeMarker.loadPlacemarkerTextures();
                }

                float cutOff = (Constants.SIZE_WORLD * Constants.SIZE_CUBE) / 2;

                if (mCamera.mPosX + cutOff < placeMarker.position.x || mCamera.mPosZ - cutOff > placeMarker.position.z) {
                    placeMarker.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);
                } else {
                    placeMarker.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);
                }
            }
        }

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE);
        // So you can see the text
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        //GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // Render GLTEXT
        if (message.length() > 0)
        {
            drawTextInFront(VMatrix, PMatrix, 0.01f, message);
        }
        // Render monsters (BIllboards, only 2 in game)
        for (GameTrigger trigger : triggers) {
            //Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, PMatrix, 0, VMatrix, 0);

            if (trigger.triggered == true && trigger.sprite != null) {
                trigger.sprite.rotation = new Vector3(0, -mCamera.mYaw, 0);
                trigger.sprite.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);
            }
        }

        // render a Sphere as the game goal
        sphere.draw(VMatrix, PMatrix);
    }
```

Comment: Per pixel lighting is not very fast

Comment: Ditto. Although there are shortcuts you can take in the shader to approximate per-pixel lighting and get a performance boost. For example, calculate normalized view direction and half direction in the vertex shader. This might require you to tessellate the mesh some depending on how much it impacts accuracy.